# SQL 2008 Stored Procedure Runs Successfully Every Other Time It Is Run

Tags: sql-server-2008

Ok, I've been stuck on this one for a day and a half now with no resolution in site.

I am running SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition (64-bit)
The stored procedure in question is at the bottom of this post

I have a stored procedure that will only run successfully every other time I execute it.  Basically what this SP does is take some values from a couple of tables (both tables on the same local server, two different databases) and inserts these values into a third table. When executed successfully the table that is the target of the insert command has a new row appended.  When it does not execute successfully I get the following errors:

```
Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

The issue happens both when I right click and execute the SP directly or when I run it from an Agent job (the Agent job, if I have it set to retry, always will end up successful on the retry).  When The "every other execution" nature of the problem is very repeatable.

The table I insert into does have a PrimaryKey, that I don't address in the SP because I let SQL handle incrementing that value.

Here is the SP (actually it's the Alter Procedure output for this SP), any ideas?

```
USE [Database1]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp210_Daily_Summary_21006]    Script Date: 02/06/2013 10:26:06 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp210_Daily_Summary_21006]

/*** 21006 ***/
@Date datetime = NULL,
@Shop_Order int = NULL,
@Lot_Number nvarchar(16) = NULL,
@Part_Number nvarchar(16) = NULL,
@Balance_Left int = NULL,
@Day_Shift_OEE real = NULL,
@Day_Shift_Good int = NULL,
@Day_Shift_Supervisor_Notes nvarchar(256) = NULL,
@Day_Shift_Tech_Notes nvarchar(256) = NULL,
@Day_Shift_Repair_Log int = NULL,
@Day_Shift_QA_Notes nvarchar(256) = NULL,
@Day_Shift_NCMR_QIF int = NULL,
@Night_Shift_OEE real = NULL,
@Night_Shift_Good int = NULL,
@Night_Shift_Supervisor_Notes nvarchar(256) = NULL,
@Night_Shift_Tech_Notes nvarchar(256) = NULL,
@Night_Shift_Repair_Log int = NULL,
@Night_Shift_QA_Notes nvarchar(256) = NULL,
@Night_Shift_NCMR_QIF int = NULL

AS
BEGIN

Set NoCount On;

Select
@Date = GETDATE(),
@Shop_Order = (Select SHOP_ORDER_NUMBER from dbo.CurrentJobSetupsAutomation WHERE (WORK_CENTER = 21006)),
@Lot_Number = (Select LOT_NUMBER from dbo.CurrentJobSetupsAutomation WHERE (WORK_CENTER = 21006)),
@Part_Number = (Select ITEM_NUMBER from dbo.CurrentJobSetupsAutomation WHERE (WORK_CENTER = 21006)),
@Balance_Left = (Select BalanceDue from dbo.CurrentJobSetupsAutomation WHERE (WORK_CENTER = 21006)),

--- Day Shift Good (7:00 AM to 7:00 PM previous day) when report runs at 6:30 AM
@Day_Shift_Good = (SELECT sum(Actual)
FROM Database2.dbo.BPAQualityLog
where AssetID = 3 
and SubQualityName = 21006
and DATEADD(HH,DATEDIFF(hour,getutcdate(),getdate()),RecordUpdated) >= DATEADD(HH,-17, DATEADD(DD,0, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE())))
and DATEADD(HH,DATEDIFF(hour,getutcdate(),getdate()),RecordUpdated) <= DATEADD(HH,-5, DATEADD(DD,0, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE())))
),

@Day_Shift_Supervisor_Notes = (Select Day_Shift_Supervisor_Notes from dbo.[210_Daily_Temp] WHERE (WORK_CENTER = 21006)),
@Day_Shift_Tech_Notes = (Select Day_Shift_Tech_Notes from dbo.[210_Daily_Temp] WHERE (WORK_CENTER = 21006)),
@Day_Shift_Repair_Log = (Select Day_Shift_Repair_Log from dbo.[210_Daily_Temp] WHERE (WORK_CENTER = 21006)),
@Day_Shift_QA_Notes = (Select Day_Shift_QA_Notes from dbo.[210_Daily_Temp] WHERE (WORK_CENTER = 21006)),
@Day_Shift_NCMR_QIF = (Select Day_Shift_NCMR_QIF from dbo.[210_Daily_Temp] WHERE (WORK_CENTER = 21006)),

--- Night Shift Good (7:00 PM to 7:00 AM current day) when report runs at 6:30 AM
@Night_Shift_Good = (SELECT sum(Actual)
FROM Database2.dbo.BPAQualityLog
where AssetID = 3 
and SubQualityName = 21006
and DATEADD(HH,DATEDIFF(hour,getutcdate(),getdate()),RecordUpdated) >= DATEADD(HH,-5, DATEADD(DD,0, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE())))
and DATEADD(HH,DATEDIFF(hour,getutcdate(),getdate()),RecordUpdated) <= DATEADD(HH,7, DATEADD(DD,0, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE())))
),

@Night_Shift_Supervisor_Notes = (Select Night_Shift_Supervisor_Notes from dbo.[210_Daily_Temp] WHERE (WORK_CENTER = 21006)),
@Night_Shift_Tech_Notes = (Select Night_Shift_Tech_Notes from dbo.[210_Daily_Temp] WHERE (WORK_CENTER = 21006)),
@Night_Shift_Repair_Log = (Select Night_Shift_Repair_Log from dbo.[210_Daily_Temp] WHERE (WORK_CENTER = 21006)),
@Night_Shift_QA_Notes = (Select Night_Shift_QA_Notes from dbo.[210_Daily_Temp] WHERE (WORK_CENTER = 21006)),
@Night_Shift_NCMR_QIF = (Select Night_Shift_NCMR_QIF from dbo.[210_Daily_Temp] WHERE (WORK_CENTER = 21006))

Set NoCount Off;

insert into [Database1].[dbo].[210_Daily_Summary]
([Date], 
[Work_Center], 
[Shop_Order], 
[Lot_Number], 
[Part_Number], 
[Balance_Left],
[Day_Shift_Good],
[Day_Shift_Supervisor_Notes],
[Day_Shift_Tech_Notes],
[Day_Shift_Repair_Log],
[Day_Shift_QA_Notes],
[Day_Shift_NCMR_QIF],
[Night_Shift_Good],
[Night_Shift_Supervisor_Notes],
[Night_Shift_Tech_Notes],
[Night_Shift_Repair_Log],
[Night_Shift_QA_Notes],
[Night_Shift_NCMR_QIF]
)

values
(@Date,
'21006', 
@Shop_Order,
@Lot_Number,
@Part_Number,
@Balance_Left,
@Day_Shift_Good,
@Day_Shift_Supervisor_Notes,
@Day_Shift_Tech_Notes,
@Day_Shift_Repair_Log,
@Day_Shift_QA_Notes,
@Day_Shift_NCMR_QIF,
@Night_Shift_Good,
@Night_Shift_Supervisor_Notes,
@Night_Shift_Tech_Notes,
@Night_Shift_Repair_Log,
@Night_Shift_QA_Notes,
@Night_Shift_NCMR_QIF
)

END
```

And here is the query I used to create the table I insert into:

```
USE [Database1]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[210_Daily_Summary]    Script Date: 02/06/2013 10:28:34 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[210_Daily_Summary](
[PrimaryKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NULL,
[Work_Center] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
[Shop_Order] [int] NULL,
[Lot_Number] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
[Part_Number] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
[Balance_Left] [int] NULL,
[Day_Shift_OEE] [real] NULL,
[Day_Shift_Good] [int] NULL,
[Day_Shift_Supervisor_Notes] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
[Day_Shift_Tech_Notes] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
[Day_Shift_Repair_Log] [int] NULL,
[Day_Shift_QA_Notes] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
[Day_Shift_NCMR_QIF] [int] NULL,
[Night_Shift_OEE] [real] NULL,
[Night_Shift_Good] [int] NULL,
[Night_Shift_Supervisor_Notes] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
[Night_Shift_Tech_Notes] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
[Night_Shift_Repair_Log] [int] NULL,
[Night_Shift_QA_Notes] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
[Night_Shift_NCMR_QIF] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, first lets make sure that you don't have  a corruption.  Run the following command and tell us the results:

```
DBCC CHECKDB (<Database Name>) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS
```

Next you want to check the SQL Server error log to see if any other errors are being logged by the server at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ran the CheckDB and only received a Command(s) Completed Successfully.  In looking at the Server Logs there are too many errors to count in the timeframes that this SP is running.  I have been having it running every 10 minutes.  I stopped that schedule from running, I will give the logs some time to get timestamp separation, then manually run the SP again twice to generate the error.  At that time I will grab the server logs and post whatever info is helpful.  Thanks again!

Comment: I ran the test and have an export of the error log.  What is the SOP for posting a fairly large dump such as this?  I don't think I can post it in less than 500 characters and I don't see an attach file mechanism.  The first few lines of the error that look to me most important:

Comment: 02/06/2013 13:07:40,spid96,Unknown,Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'

Comment: 02/06/2013 13:07:40,spid96,Unknown,SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process 96 generated fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is terminating this process.
02/06/2013 13:07:40,spid96,Unknown,***Stack Dump being sent to D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0105.txt

Comment: At this point I am going to advise you to contact MS Support.  If you are not ready to do that yet, then I suggest that you take this question and the info to someplace like SQLServerCentral.com or the Msdn forums that can better respond to this kind of complex diagnostic need.

Comment: Thank you, I posted to SQLServerCentral.  MS Support will be my next stop if I can't figure it out.